# Icon not loaded on ReactNative Android App

Tags: android, react-native

When i try to render Android App code everything is working fine but Icon not loaded and onplace of Icon cross sign display 
```
import Toolbar from 'react-native-material-design';

```
<Toolbar
    title={navigator && navigator.currentRoute ? navigator.currentRoute.title : 'RunSpace'}
    icon={navigator && navigator.isChild ? 'keyboard-backspace' : 'menu'}
    onIconPress={() => navigator && navigator.isChild ? navigator.back() : onIconPress()}
    actions={[{
        icon: 'warning',
        badge: { value: counter, animate: true },
        onPress: this.increment
    }]}
    style={{backgroundColor:"#944dff"}}
    rightIconStyle={{
        margin: 10
    }}
/>
```

The Dependency file goes like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "@remobile/react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.3",
    "alt": "^0.18.4",
    "native-base": "^0.3.1",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-native": "^0.25.1",
    "react-native-action-button": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-android-statusbar": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-icons": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-material-design": "https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design-styles.git",
    "react-native-material-design-styles": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-navigation-bar": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.3"
  },
```

Comment: you have set up your material design library correctly but , the icon is not shown due to vector-icons font are not available. so you need to install vector icon fonts library manually with the help of this: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android After you installed library link this library with material design library. you will get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not included the native module in your project. For this refer readme from react-native-vector-icons on [github](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

You have to add that module into your MainActivity.java file